# write two matlab vectors in a file and insert backslash between the vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, printf

Given

```
a=[1 2 3];
b=[4 5 6];
Output in file should look like:
1 2 3 / 4 5 6
```

Is there a way to achieve this in one single fprintf() call?

I have a solution where there is no backslash between `a` and `b`

```
fprintf(fileID, '%d %d ', a, b);
output:
1 2 3 4 5 6 (no backslash in between)
```

Comment: So add the slash... `fprintf(fileID, '%d / %d ', a, b);`

Comment: This will add a backslash after every element, i.e., `1 / 2 / 3  / 4 / 5 / 6`

Comment: Why does this need to be a single `fprintf` call? Just do three.

Comment: Of course it can be three calls. I just wanted to make sure that there is no obvious solution (which I do not see) to my issue.

Comment: `fprintf(fileID, '%d %d %d / %d %d %d ', a, b)` then, you can generate the format spec using `repmat` to repeat `%d` for as many elements as `a` or `b` have

Comment: What is fileID?

Comment: @iohans The file in which the output should be written as returned by `fileID= fopen('my_file.txt')´

Comment: `sprintf('%d%c',[a,b;+'  /   '])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a single call to fprintf if you’re willing to construct your format string dynamically.

```
fileID=1;
a=[1,2,3];
b=[4,5,6,7];
c=[8,9];

fprintf(fileID,strjoin(cellfun(@(c)sprintf('%d ',c),{a,b,c},'UniformOutput',false),'/ '));
```

It’s not pretty, and it’s probably only worth the trouble if you’ve got a lot of calls to fprintf in a loop and need to avoid overhead, but technically it achieves what you asked for.

Comment: For what it's worth, calling `cellfun` is really just a "loop in disguise", it's only visually a one-liner, and doesn't aid in anything else (i.e. performance), but this does answer the letter of the question so +1

Comment: True, the `cellfun` probably even adds a bit of overhead. I was referring more to replacing many calls to `fprintf` with many calls to `sprintf`. If you can afford the space overhead, I’ve gotten faster execution times this way.